# Why my Y coordinate is reversed?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, coordinates

I got stuck just with one problem:
 I don't have even an idea why my Y coordinate is reversed.

Here is the scheme: Y is 50 and my object is on the top. (I use only drawing. No rotation or other stuff) Stage is 400x400.

Comment: Dear StackOverflow users! I have written this question long time ago, there is no need to vote it down. Nobody reads the question, it is still here because there is no way to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates used in flash are the same as many other 2D graphics libraries, including GDI (Win32) and x-windows where (0,0) is the top left corner.  So positive X is to the right and positive Y is downwards.